# How to apply input and output stress using stress-ng

Tags: stress-testing, workload, stress

I have an application which sends frames from client to server using I/O bound package async, which provides single-threaded, multiplexing I/O access over sockets.

I run stress-ng cpu and memory test with 10-90 % with ten-step on the client-side. But I noticed it was not affecting the application performance. I then realised my application is just sending frames from client to server and on server frames are being processed so its I/O bound. I need to ask how to stress for this scenario. After googling I came about the below command but I am unable to use it for my scenario due to my limited knowledge and understanding. How would I stress using below command in percentage, for instance, 10%,20%,..90% for input and output bound task.

Thanks help is highly appreciated for pointing me in the right direction.

```
sudo stress-ng --io 10%
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test with respect to your application?

Comment: I am testing frame drop rate of the application which is affected by network and processing latency, so I have cpu stress, ram stress and I need IO test too. @SergiyKolesnikov Thanks

Comment: The processing latency can be controlled fully locally on the machine, but for the network latency there are factors that are out of your control, such as, overloaded routers or packets tacking a longer route. How are you going to account for these in your test?

Comment: Thanks for your respond @SergiyKolesnikov for network I am stressing using traffic control shaper linux

Comment: I still don't fully understand the test setup and what's missing. Also, it looks like Server Fault or Unix&Linux are a better place to ask such questions. Maybe you can fully describe your setup and what exactly you want to achieve on one of those sites.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolesnikov for pointing out to me to right place to post my question